# Convert form data to JSON with sub arrays

Tags: python, html, json, flask

I make a server with Flask.
I want to get form with data and convert it to json file.

example

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input name="your_name" value="" />
  <input name="animal[1][name]" value="" />
  <input name="animal[1][age]" value="" />
  <input name="animal[2][name]" value="" />
  <input name="animal[2][age]" value="" />
  <button type="submit">test</button>
</form>
```

and I expect to this:

```
{
    "your_name" : "my_name",
    "animal":[
      {
         "name": "mono",
         "age":"12"
       },
       { 
         "name": "jir",
         "age":"34"
       }
    ]
  }
}
```

if someone know how to do it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=["POST"])
def process():
    your_name = request.form['your_name']
    (... do the same here for all your form fields ...)

    your_json = {}
    your_json["your_name"] = your_name
    your_json["animal"] = ...
```